# Easy way to determine if typescript code is running in jasmine/karma test or not?

Tags: typescript

I have a static method to create a service-like object, which is accessed by a static method, something like this.

```
expect class FooService {
   private static instance : FooService;
   static getInstance() {
        if (!this.instance) {
           this.instance = new FooService();
        }
        return this.instance
  private constructor() {}
  [implementation]
```

}

What I would like to do is to know if the getInstance() is being run in my Angular application, or if its being run in a unit test, so I can return a mock version instead of the real thing.

something like:

```
 expect class FooService {
   private static instance : FooService;
   static getInstance() {
        if (isInJasmineTest()} {              <----
           return new MockFooService() 
        } 
        if (!this.instance) {
           this.instance = new FooService();
        }
        return this.instance
  private constructor() {}
  [implementation]
```

}

I know there are lots of ways with spys and mocks and injection to achieve this, but

**I'm just wondering how to implement** `isInJasmineTest()`?

I guess I could write some kind of function that is called in the beforeAll of each Jasmine test
like setJasmineTestEnvironment(true) but wondering if there is already something present I could check without having to create a function like this.

Answer (score 0):

**If you run your tests with Karma, the following could help.**

Since Karma injects a few things into the DOM to run it's tests. You could search for the presence of those.

e.g.

`document.getElementById('banner');` Is injected in the top of the body and shows the Karma banner you see above all the HTML test output.

Also

`const isKarma = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML === 'Karma';`

Karma sets the page title to it's own name. So checking that could also be a viable solution.

To access the DOM from a you need to inject it.

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
// We import DOCUMENT from @angular/common.
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: HTMLDocument){}
```

Then you can treat `this.document` like the `document` you'd usually use in an Angular component

Comment: The tests do run in Karma, but FooService is a just a typescript class.  So it wouldn't have access to a document object would it?

Comment: I've added an explanation on how to access the DOM in my answer, from a service. The only way you can do this is if you make your service @Injectable() and also change to instance members rather than a static method. Is there any reason why you can't do this? It makes a lot of Angular wizardry so much easier.

Comment: The service is injectable, but has a lot of dependencies, so to inject it means a lot of configuration in beforeall etc, so being able to replace about 30 lines of configuration with just DataService.getInstance() means a lot of my tests will be a lot less tedious to set up.  I realize this isn't the angular way, but the angular way seems to have way too much overhead for my taste.  I jsut solved this with a global utility function isJasmineTest() that I set in the beforeAll and its all a lot less paingful.

Comment: In the test to get this service. Have you tried const myServiceInstance = TestBed.get(Service) ? This allows you to access an instance of your service without worrying about it's dependencies.